# How to evaluate the transfer function f(h) for a set of two synsets

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet

How to evaluate the transfer function f(h) for a set of two synsets(Synonym sets) which is used to evaluate the sentence similarity based on semantic nets and corpus.
Here what exactly does 'h' stands for?
http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf

Comment: According to the paper, "h is the depth of subsumer in the hierarchical semantic nets". Look at page 4 for a description.

Comment: @Lgiro From which point should the depth be taken?I was not getting that is it from 'entity' or is there any other hypernym that is the root to all possible words ?